# how to mock a method which returns future java object ,using mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a method validate for which i need to write junit test cases

```
public List<Field> validate(){

        final Future<Map<ObjectId, Field>> uniqueResult = globalUniqValidator.execute(uniqueValidations,
                validationContent.getEvalFieldValueMap(), inputFieldValuesMap);

        final Future<Map<ObjectId, Field>> subnetResult = globalSubnetValidator.execute(subnetValidations,
                validationContent.getEvalFieldValueMap(), inputFieldValuesMap, surveyTemplateRefId);
}
```

it has two methods which returns future object

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GlobalValidationServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private Future<Map<ObjectId, Field>> future;

    @Test
    public void validateGlobalValidation() throws Exception {

    given(globalUniqValidator.execute(uniqueValidations, validationContent.getEvalFieldValueMap(), inputFieldValuesMap)).willReturn(future);
    when(future.get()).thenReturn(inputFieldValuesMap);



    given(globalSubnetValidator.execute(globalValidation, evalFieldValueMap, inputFieldValuesMap, surveyTemplateRefId)).willReturn(future);
    when(future.get()).thenReturn(inputFieldValuesMap_subnet);


    }
```

however when I debug I get a null for both uniqueResult  and subnetResult
i guess it is not being mocked

it also says unused mock at the lines where the mock is written

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I think you are missing `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` before tests.

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov should not be needed since it's being run with `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

Comment: @Kayaman yeah, you are right,  I didn't noticed the runner.

Comment: Where do you inject your `Future` object? It has to be injected into your OUT.

Comment: yes i have injected it at the top  
  @Mock
  private Future<Map<ObjectId, Field>> future;